# Arquillian with Mockito and CDI

Tags: testing, mockito, cdi, jboss-arquillian

Is it possible to create spy(mock) object in testing class?

Here is tested class.

```java
@Stateless
@Slf4j
public class UserDao {

    @Inject
    private TestBean testBean;

    public String mock() {
        return testBean.mock();
    }

    public String notMock() {
        return testBean.notMock();
    }
}
```

TestBean code

```java
@Stateless
@Slf4j
public class TestBean {
    public String notMock() {
        return "NOT MOCK";
    }

    public String mock() {
        return "IMPLEMENTED MOCK";
    }
}
```

Here's my test

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class UserDataTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Inject
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Deployment
    protected static Archive createWar() {

        File[] dependencies = Maven.configureResolver()
                .withRemoteRepo("nexus-remote", "http://maven.wideup.net/nexus/content/groups/public/", "default")
                .withRemoteRepo("nexus-release", "http://maven.wideup.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/", "default")
                .resolve(
                        "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7",
                        "eu.bitwalker:UserAgentUtils:1.15",
                        "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.8"
                ).withoutTransitivity().asFile();

        return ShrinkWrap
                .create(WebArchive.class, "pass.jpa.war")
                .addAsWebInfResource("jbossas-ds.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource("jboss-deployment-structure.xml")
                .addAsLibraries(
                        PassApiDeployments.createDefaultDeployment(),
                        PassUtilLibrary.createDefaultDeployment(),
                        PassJpaDeployments.createDefaultDeployment()
                ).addAsLibraries(dependencies);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMock() {
        assertEquals("MOCK", userDao.mock());
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotMock() {
        assertEquals("NOT MOCK", userDao.notMock());
    }
}
```

I'd like to create a spy object on TestBean to change result on method test() of this bean.

So is it possible to create TestBean spy in UserDao.

I solve some problems through producer like this.

```java
@Singleton
public class MockFactory {
    @Produces
    @ArquillianAlternative
    public TestBean getTestBean() {
        return when(mock(TestBean.class).mock()).thenReturn("MOCK").getMock();
    }
}
```

But in this example I need create on Bean completely on my own. And if it is bean with additional dependencies and thus i will manage all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, its not possible to use a mocking framework in combination with arquillian ...

Comment: From my example you could see that it's possible to use mocks. And it works pretty fine. But problem was about constructing the hole mock not a spy. I solved my problem but it became not related to this post.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but this Arquillian extension seems to be specifically designed to support Mockito Spy objects in an Arquillian test: https://github.com/topikachu/arquillian-extension-mockito/