# How to test Rest API with Arquillian and Mock

Tags: java, rest, mockito, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I would like to test following class implements JAX-RS with CDI Injects inside.

```
@Path("area")
public class AreaService {

    @Inject
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Logger logger;

    @Context
    private SecurityContext context;

    @Inject
    private AreaGateway areaGateway;

    @GET
    @Path("{area-name}/team-project/{tp-id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAreaByTeamProjectAndName(@PathParam("tp-id") long tpId, @PathParam("area-name") String areaName)
            throws WebApplicationException {

        Area area = areaGateway.getAreaByTeamProjectAndName(tpId, areaName);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(area).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("team-project/{tp-id}")
    @Auditable
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createArea(@PathParam("tp-id") long tpId, @Payload Area area) throws WebApplicationException {
        long areaId = areaGateway.createArea(tpId, area, context);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(areaId).build();
    }
}
```

I have choosen Arquillian as test framework and I have used [the extension](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-rest) for the REST APIs.

In particular i have tried to follow the Warp REST example, but i can't find a clean and clear sample to test my REST API with mocking inject dependency like AreaGateway with any mocking framework like Mockito.

I would like to do something like this:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class RestClientTestCase {

    @ArquillianResource
    public URL contextPath;


    private AreaService areaService;
    private AreaGateway areaGateway;

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive create() {
        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addClasses(SLF4JProducer.class, AreaGateway.class, JAXRSActivator.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "WEB-INF/beans.xml");

        MavenResolverSystem resolver = Maven.resolver();
        war.addAsLibraries(resolver.loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").resolve("org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.8").withTransitivity().asSingleFile());
        return war;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        // initializes the rest easy client framework
        RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        areaGateway = Mockito.mock(AreaGateway.class);//real bean replaced by mocked one
        Mockito.when(areaGateway.getAreaByTeamProjectAndName(0, "areaName")).thenReturn(new Area());

        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        ResteasyWebTarget  target = client.target("" + "rest");
        areaService = target.proxy(AreaService.class);
    }

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void testStockGetWarp() {

        Response response = areaService.getAreaByTeamProject(0);
        assertEquals("The service returned status code.", 201, response.getStatus());
        response.close();
    }
}
```

Could someone help me to develop minimal test sample with exact Maven dependencies? Is it possible to mock CDI dependency with some framework according to Arquillian?

Comment: I am not sure how mocking frameworks operate with CDI but if you just instruct it to use `new Area()` instead of doing it the "CDI-way" (leaving the object creation to CDI), then CDI will not handle such object's lifecycle at all. It just won't know you did that and the `Area` object will not have any dependencies resolved. I would suggest that you instead use alternatives/decorators which you only enable in testing environment. There, you can fully avoid mocking and take full advantage of CDI.

Comment: It's not a complete example, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267717/arquillian-with-mockito-and-cdi) shows a CDI producer which produces a mock object with Mockito. I think it might be based on this: http://jeefix.com/how-to-inject-mockito-mock-into-cdi-context-with-arquillian-involved/